# Is possible to rewrite /mystring_value/ to ?parameter=value?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is possible to rewrite this URL:

```
http://wwww.mywebsite.com/number_one/
```

to this URL:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/?n=one
```

in .htaccess?

Comment: uhhh my mind reader might be defective, but it can't pick up the context for this question. Is this a software development question? Which language/technology are you talking about?

Comment: how does `value` and `mystring_value` correspond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you want to do this using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  In that case, what you need is a `RewriteCond` to match the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ number_%1?
```

(The `?` at the end of the `RewriteRule` tells mod_rewrite to discard the old query string.)

Also note that, as written, this is an internal rewrite.  If you want the change to be visible to the user, append the flag `[R]` (or `[R=301]` if you want a permanent redirect) to the `RewriteRule`.

---

**Edit:** If you want to go the other way, from `site.com/number_one` to `site.com/?n=one` as your question now reads, it's even easier:

```
RewriteRule ^number_([^/]+) ?n=$1
```

(As written, this rewrite rule will throw away anything after the first slash following the number, as well as any existing query string parameters. You can keep the original query string by adding the `[QSA]` flag to the rule if you want.)

Comment: Sorry for the mess, I've reversed the question

Comment: What are differences with this string? ( added \. and ?$ )
`RewriteRule ^number_([^/\.]+)/?$ ?n=$1`

Comment: `[^/]` matches anything but a slash, `[^/.]` (the backslash is unnecessary) matches anything but a slash or a period. Also, my version allows (and ignores) anything after the end of the match (since there's no `$` anchor), while yours allows only a single slash or nothing.